# jQuery, Display none first LI in UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im just wondering if what I want to do is possible with jQuery...

I have the following...

```
<ul class="navmenu">
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Someting</li>
    <li>Something</li>
</ul>
```

What i want to do is display:none; the first LI within .navmenu, is this possible?

Comment: Sure, have lot ways to do that, try to read the docs http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ even google can answer that for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
$('.navmenu > li:first-child').hide();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pApr/2/) Example.

You also may want to check out the [jQuery Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) and [jQuery Selectors API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) as this is a pretty basic usage of jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

`<sarcasm>`No, you can't do it. Ever.`</sarcasm>`

```
$('.navmenu li:first').hide()
```

Comment: Unfortunately there's no html tag called sarcasm so the browser will not know you're being sarcastic :-/ for a complete list of valid tags please look here http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/

Comment: Good catch, I'm luckily they were wrapped in `<code/>` tags or my browser may have exploded from parsing them.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder, for the complete list of valid tags I would use the [HTML5 Spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/spec.html). Of course, my markup was XML, and perfectly valid with my custom DTD.

Answer (score 2):

CSS Solution (this should prevent the first element from flickering on page load):

```
.navmenu > li:first-child {display: none;}
```

Comment: assuming that he is running it on page load.

Answer (score 1):

sure,

```
$('ul.navmenu li:first').css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a descendant selector, `>`, to select the `li` children of the `ul` with the `navmenu` class name, then use the `first-child` pseudo class to select just the first one. Then you can set css styles using the `css` method:

```
$("ul.navmenu > li:first-child").css("display", "none")
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/uDeQE/1/

Answer (score 0):

Yep, certainly is:

```
$('.navmenu li:first')
```

You could also user the pseudo selector in CSS if its styling you're after:

.navmenu li:first-child